# I am not able to install Android studio after downloading it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

1. I have downloaded and installed JDK tool in my programx86 for windows 32.
2. I have set `JAVA_HOME` AND `JDK_HOME` variables. I have also set path.
3. I checked in the command prompt if JDK is installed and it is showing me version 1.8
4. Then, I downloaded Android studio.zip for windows 32.
5. Unzipped it, and saved it in the programx86 folder.
6. Now, I am suppose to run studio.bat and get the android window. But, in actual, when I click on `studio.bat`, I just get a flash and then nothing happens.

I tried everything. Uninstalling/installing java again and again. Setting the java path. Changing the location of Android studio. 
But, it is not working for me. I am not getting the android installed. Please someone help.

I have a error file in my recent files. When I opened it, it has long text but the main msg is "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x33773dd4, pid=7404, tid=0x00003898
#

## JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b02) (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

## Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (25.152-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )"

If this gives you a clue.

Comment: Why don't you try the exe download instead of the zip file.

Comment: On the website "https://developer.android.com/studio/", there is only one option for windows 32 and that is studio.zip . It says "android-studio-ide-173.4819257-windows32.zip". It also mentioned no .exe installer.

Answer (score 1):

try to run .bat as Administrator. or for easy simply download [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and install.

Comment: I downloaded Android studio for windows 32. Then only I started getting this problem. I tried to run .bat but it flashes for a moment and then goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I was having the same issue as you and here's what fixed it for me: setting a system variable named `STUDIO_JDK` to the path of your JDK installation `("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181" in my case)` then run "studio.bat".

Looking inside the .bat it looks like Android Studio checks `STUDIO_JDK` before `JAVA_HOME` or `JDK_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

i also face same issue ,but i resolved it.
Please check your C drive have proper space or not if no than make some good space.
if done that please check your android studio will run .

or

remove older version from your device and it will automatically start working .
Thanks !